# Как при чтении файла excel в dataframe не преобразовывать тип данных?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Есть некоторое количество столбцов с датами (сколько их и где они находятся неизвестно), при преобразовании с помощью pandas.read_excel() даты теряются формат (формат тоже нам неизвестен), как сделать так чтобы pandas не считал их за даты или хотя бы восстанавливал формат.

Какой изначально

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или может быть такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В какой преобразует

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

попытка решить таким способом, object тоже не помогает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не получилась, он всё равно меняет формат отображения даты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так то вроде даты он правильно же распознал, в чём проблема? В нулевом времени? )

Comment: @CrazyElf в том что он местами все поменял

Comment: А, так это вопрос отображения данных, даты он правильно распознал

Comment: я тоже не понимаю, что вам не нравится. дата распознана верно. то, что там год идет сначала, а не день месяца - это вопрос отображения.

Comment: В этом и проблема, я условно не знаю в каком формате время, а pandas сносит на свой формат

Comment: Там нет времени, только дата фактически. Выводить дату можете в каком хотите формате. Хранится она правильно.

Comment: Формат не статичный, то есть в одной таблице excel он один, а других иной формат и как понять в каком формате изначально он был

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы pandas не предполагала тип данных значений, попробуйте указать эти типы данных явно. Как сказано в [документации](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), `Use object to preserve data as stored in Excel and not interpret dtype`. например:

```
pd.read_excel("file", dtype="object")
```

Comment: проблема все равно остается, он меняет формат времени

Comment: проблема в том, что excel сам определяет как дату

Comment: @greymaster ну приведите пример данных тогда в вопросе. ссылку на файлообменник